# Is it true that every orthogonal transformation , even over $\mathbb R$, is diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, operator-theory, transformation

Is it true that every orthogonal transformation , even over $\mathbb R$, is diagonalizable? I didn't succeed to get any information about it. Could anyone explain please?

Comment: Diagonalizable over $\mathbb R$?

Comment: yes. and what abut the complex field?

Comment: Any real orthogonal transformation is diagonalizable over $\mathbb C$.

Comment: Okay, and over R it is not true, right?

Comment: Right, as shown by the example in my answer.

Answer (score 7):

Let me go a little farther.  Let $n$ be a positive integer, and let $L: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be a linear transformation.

1) Then $L$ has an invariant subspace of dimension either $1$ or $2$.  The former occurs if and only if $L$ has a real eigenvalue.

Proof: It is immediate that existence of real eigenvalues is equivalent to existence of 
$1$-dimensional invariant subspaces.  So suppose $L$ has no real eigenvalue.  Then, since the complex eigenvalues are roots of the real polnomial $\chi(t) = \operatorname{det} (t\cdot 1_{\mathbb{R^n}}-L)$, for a complex eigenvalue $\lambda$ (which exists by the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra), also the complex conjugate $\overline{\lambda}$ is an eigenvalue, and if $v \in \mathbb{C}^n$ is such that $Lv = \lambda v$, then taking complex conjugates and using $L = \overline{L}$ we get

$L \overline{v} = \overline{\lambda} \overline{v}$.

Then

$$V = \operatorname{span}_{\mathbb{R}} \{ \frac{v+\overline{v}}{2}, \frac{v-\overline{v}}{2i} \}$$

is a two-dimensional (real!) invariant subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

[Remark aside: if you are willing to assume the **Real Fundamental Theorem of Algebra** -- namely that every nonconstant real polynomial has a factor of degree one or two -- then you can establish the above fact without using complex numbers, considering factors of the local minimal polynomial ($=$ the annihilator polynomial) of any nonzero $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$.  I have recently been kicking around whether it is possible to show RFTA using real linear algebra only.  So far no luck.]

2) If $L$ is orthogonal (respectively, symmetric), then for any invariant subspace $V \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, also the orthogonal complement $V^{\perp} = \{w \in \mathbb{R^n} \mid w \cdot v = 0 \forall v \in V\}$ is an invariant subspace, and $L|_{V^{\perp}}$ remains orthogonal (respectively, symmetric).

From 1) and 2) we see that if $L$ is orthogonal (or symmetric), then $\mathbb{R}^n$ is an orthogonal direct sum of subspaces of dimension $1$ or $2$.  In the symmetric case is turns out that one can go farther and take the subspaces to be of dimension $1$ (this is the **Real Spectral Theorem**).  A little thought shows that this is equivalent to:

3) If $L$ is symmetric, then all the complex eigenvalues of $L$ are actually real numbers.  (Or more gracefully: $\chi(t)$ splits into linear factors over $\mathbb{R}.)

Once again there is the standard proof involving showing that complex eigenvalues of a symmetric matrix must be real, and there is also a totally real proof using RFTA.  (I have to run shortly, so I omit these details for now.  The first proof is of course very standard: it appears in most linear algebra books.)

Now let us look at the case in which $L$ is orthogonal.  Then:

4) The complex eigenvalues of an orthogonal matrix all lie on the unit circle.  In particular the only possible real eigenvalues are $\pm 1$.

(Again I omit the standard proof for now.)

Thus a real orthogonal transformation is diagonalizable if and only if it is the direct sum of its $1$-eigenspace and its $-1$-eigenspace.  This is a strong condition: in particular its trace must be an integer.  Let's look more closely at the $n = 2$ case, since the key question is when a $2$-dimensional invariant subspace has an eigenvalue.

Since $L$ is orthogonal, $L((1,0))$ and $L((0,1))$ form an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$: here this means that both are unit vectors and that their dot product is zero.  We can write any unit vector as $(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$ and thus take $L((1,0))$ to be in this form, and then there are two perpendicular unit vectors: $(-\sin \theta, \cos \theta)$ and $(\sin \theta,-\cos \theta)$, leading to the two standard matrices

$R_{\theta} = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} \cos \theta & - \sin \theta \\ \sin \theta & \cos \theta \end{array} \right]$

and

$T_{\theta} = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} \cos \theta &  \sin \theta \\ \sin \theta & -\cos \theta \end{array} \right]$.

In the first case the characteristic polynomial is $t^2 - 2 \cos \theta t + 1$, of discriminant $4(\cos^2 \theta -1)$.  Thus we have real eigenvalues if and only if $\cos \theta = \pm 1$; these values correspond to the scalar matrices $\pm 1$.  For all other values we do not have real eigenvalues, so we see that a two-dimensional orthogonal transformation with determinant $1$ almost never has a real eigenvalue.  However, because we do not have real roots, the quadratic formula guarantees us that there \emph{distinct} eigenvalues $\lambda \neq \overline{\lambda} \in \mathbb{C}$ and thus $R_{\theta}$ is diagonalizable over $\mathbb{C}$.

In the second case the characteristic polynomial is $t^2-1 = (t+1)(t-1)$, so indeed we have real eigenvalues.  More specifically $T_{\theta}$ is the the matrix of orthogonal reflection through $(\cos \theta,\sin \theta)$.

In summary we have proved:

> Every real orthogonal linear transformation $L$ is orthogonally equivalent to a block diagonal matrix consisting of $1 \times 1 $ blocks $[1]$, $1 \times 1$ blocks $[-1]$, and/or $2 \times 2$ blocks $R_{\theta}$ for $\theta \in (0,2\pi) \setminus \pi$.  $L$ is diagonalizable (equivalently, orthogonally diagonalizable) over $\mathbb{R}$ if and only if no $2 \times 2$ blocks appear.  In all cases $L$ is diagonalizable over $\mathbb{C}$.

It seems to me that the above result is a close relative of the Real Spectral Theorem.  Since orthogonal matrices appear as prominently or more so in introductory linear algebra than symmetric matrices, I am surprised not to find it in most of the standard texts.

Answer (score 5):

No, take $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1\\ -1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ or, for a $n\times n$ matrix with $n\ge 3$, take $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & \dots & 0\\ -1 & 0 & 0 &\ldots & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & \dots & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 &\ddots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 1 \end{bmatrix}$.

Both of these matrices have $i$ and $-i$ as eigenvalues and hence aren't diagonalizable over $\mathbb R$.

However any real orthogonal matrix is diagonalizable over $\mathbb C$.

Comment: Complex orthogonal matrix (not a complex untary matrix) is diagonalizable... reference?

Comment: @GEdgar: I think that by "orthogonal matrix" he means "real orthogonal matrix".  (As you hint, I believe it is not the case that every complex orthogonal matrix is diagonalizable.)  I do wish that the answers here would be more explicit about the distinction between real and complex scalars.  (As I do in my lengthy, apparently not so popular answer...)

Comment: @GEdgar Contrarily to what happens with symmetric matrices, I believe matrix orthogonality is only defined for real matrices. I've never seen orthogonality defined for non-real matrices.

Comment: For a square matrix, the transpose is equal to the inverse.  This makes sense for any field!  But it seems you meant only real orthogonal in your answer.

Comment: @GitGud: Orthogonal groups are well studied over all fields (and even more general rings).  For instance, over finite fields they produce one of the families of finite simple groups.  In this more general context an orthogonal group is associated to a quadratic form.  But if the field is not formally real, then the "standard" form $x_1^2 + \ldots+ x_n^2$ is not particularly sacred.

Comment: @GEdgar Despite the fact that it makes sense, my claim is it isn't done. If you google *orthogonal matrix*, three out of the first four links require the matrix to be real.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark As I mention in the comment above, I don't think the usual definition allow us to conclude that the statement $\text{For all square matrices}(QQ^T=I\implies Q\text{ is an orthogonal matrix}$ is always true, simply because the (usual) definition of orthogonal matrix requires it to be real. I'm not opposed to being convinced that I'm wrong, but I'm opening books and lecture notes on the web and almost every source supports my belief. It would be understandable if the notes only dealt with real matrices, but often times they also deal with complex matrices.

Comment: @GitGud: I checked around a bit too, and I largely agree with you: while one can certainly find sources (including the wikipedia article on orthogonal matrices) indicating that the definition is meaningful over an arbitrary field, nevertheless the term *orthogonal matrix* largely pertains to the real (or at least formally real) case.  I think the point is that we want the quadratic form $x_1^2+\ldots+x_n^2$ to be isotropic so that $V \cap V^{\perp} = \{0\}$.  This property is equivalent to formal reality; when it fails, an "orthogonal matrix" doesn't have the corresponding allure.

Comment: Anyway, thanks for editing the word "real" into your answer.  I have seen a lot of linear algebra questions on this site fall prey to field-of-scalars-ambiguity.  It certainly doesn't hurt to err on the side of explicitness.

Comment: I heard Marvin Marcus talk about complex orthogonal matrices once (back when I was a student).  I don't remember what he said about them, though.

Answer (score 2):

$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$.

This cannot be diagonalizable over the reals since the eigenvalues are complex.

Comment: I apologize, I had already given this answer, then I changed it due to some confusion in my head and I've went back to it again.

Comment: No problem! There are lots of matrices to go around :-).

Comment: Well this matrix $S$ is better known for its action on the upper half plane as an element of the full modular group, unfortunately it's not an orthogonal matrix...simply because its transpose takes an element of upper half plane Im$z >0$ to an element of the lower half plane Im$z <0$...!

Comment: @Affineline: The above matrix is orthogonal.

Comment: Oh God...! I am hallucinating...terribly sorry... :-D .. ${\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
\cos{\theta} & -\sin{\theta}\\
\sin{\theta} & \cos{\theta}
\end{array}
\right]}$ is orthogonal for every $\theta \in \ \mathbb{R}$ ... I vaguely recall writing this comment... thanks for pointing out my mistake... I don't want to delete the comment so that I am reminded of my idiotic mistake.... (this is an non-symmetric matrix, and as an element of "$PSL_2(\mathbb{Z})$" and NOT  $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ this element has order 2... ) ... Once again apologies for the mistake... regards -

Answer (score 0):

The orthogonal transformations of $\mathbb R ^2$ are rotations and reflexions through a line. Do you know a vector which is invariant under rotations? (Ans: $v=O$).

Answer (score 0):

An orthogonal matrix $U$ is a normal matrix (i.e., $UU^T=U^TU$), and thus it is diagonalizable. Its eigenvalues have absolute value 1, but they do not have to be real.

Comment: The question seems to be asking for the difference between diagonalizability over $\mathbb{R}$ and over $\mathbb{C}$, so it would be nice if your answer indicated that you are discussing diagonalizability over $\mathbb{C}$.